# Compare the value of a cell with the value of another cell in Excel 2003

Tags: vba, excel

I want to compare the value of cell A(1..17) with B(1..17), if the value is the same so add a comment "Found" for B(1..17).

The following code does not work in Excel 2003

```
For i = 1 To 17
        If Range("A" & i).Value = Range("B" & i).Value Then
            Range("B" & i).AddComment ("Found")
        End If
Next i
```

I receive the error : 
Run-time error '13': Type mismatch

Thanks

Comment: There isn't enough information here to duplicate this error. I've tried this on several data sets and no problems.

Answer (score 1):

I found :

```
If Range("A" & i).Text = Range("B" & i).Text Then
```

Comment: Ahhhhhhh I see now. One of the cells in the range has an error value which is causing the type mismatch. This is why you should include sample data as well.

Answer (score 0):

Let's add what you haven't told us here. Here's a simple repro.

1. In Cell $A$1 enter a `1`.
2. In Cell $B$1 enter `=#NULL!`
3. The code to repro:

   ```
   Public Sub HasTroubleWithSpreadSheetErrors()
       If Range("A1").Value = Range("B1").Value Then ' Error #13 Mismatched Type here
           Debug.Print "Found"
       End If
   ```

As you already found, you can get around this by comparing the `.Text` property instead of the `.Value` property.

```
If Range("A1").Text = Range("B1").Text Then ' no error
```

But as an alternative, you can also check to see if either cell is in error using the `IsError` function.

```
If IsError(Range("A1")) Or IsError(Range("A2")) Then
    If Range("A1").Value = Range("B1").Value Then
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't add a comment where one already exists. It sounds like this comment may already exist from a previous iteration of your loop. I would suggest to always remove the "found" comment in `Column B` to allow this sub/loop to provide accurate information in `Column B` every time it runs.

```
Sub test()
    For i = 1 To 17

        ' clear the comments, you cant add a new comment when one already exists.
        Range("B" & i).ClearComments

        If Range("A" & i).Value = Range("B" & i).Value Then
             Range("B" & i).AddComment ("Found") ' if this cell contains a comment from a previous iteration, it throws an exception.
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```